# Unable To Read Messages From Kafka Topic Using Spark Streaming Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The following code is meant to read messages from Kafka using Spark Submit.
The code executes and terminates without errors but reads no messages(The output file is empty and the log inside rdd.foreachPartition does not print).Please indicate what i am missing.

```
package hive;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import scala.Tuple2;
public class SparkKafka1 {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkKafka1.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "http://192.168.1.214:9092,http://192.168.1.214:9093");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    //kafkaParams.put("group.id", "StreamingGroup");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    String user = "ankit";
    String password = "noida@123";
    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("StreamingTopic");
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://192.168.1.214:7077")
    .set("spark.deploy.mode", "cluster").set("user",user)
    .set("password",password).set("spark.driver.memory", "1g").set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.1.214:9000")
    .setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,new Duration(500));
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
      KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        streamingContext,
        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
      );

    stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
    stream.foreachRDD(rdd ->{            
        rdd.foreachPartition(item ->{
            while (item.hasNext()) {    
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+item.next());
                logger.info("next item="+item.next());
}
});
});
    logger.info("demo log="+stream.count());
    stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
          OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();
          rdd.foreachPartition(consumerRecords -> {
            OffsetRange o = offsetRanges[TaskContext.get().partitionId()];
            System.out.println(
              o.topic() + " " + o.partition() + " " + o.fromOffset() + " " + o.untilOffset());
            rdd.saveAsTextFile("/home/ankit/work/warehouse/Manish.txt");
             logger.info("tokenizing inside processElement method");
          });
        });
}
}
```

The following is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SparkTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <name>SparkTest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-flume_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided </scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                            <filter>
                           <artifact>org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifact>
                           <includes>                             <include>org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/**</include>
                           </includes>
                           </filter>  
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The following command submits the job:

```
./spark-submit   --class hive.SparkKafka1   --master spark://192.168.1.214:6066   --deploy-mode cluster   --supervise   --executor-memory 2G   --total-executor-cores 4 hdfs://192.168.1.214:9000/input/SparkTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

i haven't run this program to see but it seems you are using kafka 0.10.2 and smallest is deprecated please use earliest instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this two commands;

1. streamingContext.start();//start this app.
2. streamingContext.awaitTermination();//prevent this app close.

And I see you use http* value for bootstrap.servers. Delete the http prefix.
By the way, if you set spark conf in the code. It's useless set the same value in the command line.
Just check it. If the error exist as before. please let me know.